# language good enough to develop WebGL appication?

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, webgl

what is the best web language to develop WebGL application?
and why?
is this language support HTML 5?
is there WebGL framework compatible with this web language?
and is the best way to Learn WebGL that's i must have a background in OpenGL?
and can i setup that's environment under linux?

i have [torrent](http://www.demonoid.me/files/details/2370269/8055882/) that's help me to learn game development
if you can check it and show me what i nedd form it to learn WebGL as profiessional

please answer those questions and explain which IDE i can use ??
if you have any materials or tutorials or examples don't be shy to share with us

thx alot:)

Answer (score 3):

WebGL is an OpenGL ES 2.0 binding to *JavaScript*. So there is exactly and *only* one language you can develop WebGL in: JavaScript.

Oh, you can feed that JavaScript data from other languages. But JavaScript is the only one that can directly talk to WebGL.